# How are the individual bits accessed in this code?

Tags: c

So I saw this code which printed out individual bits of any number.I do not understand why the individual bits are accessed and not the entire number itself

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=10, b;   
    for(b=0; x!=0; x>>=1) {
        printf("%d:%d\n", b, (x&1));
        b++;   
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0:0 
1:1 
2:0 
3:1
```

Please help me understand this piece of code.

Comment: There is no way to access individual bites. It just obtains a sequence of `0` and `1` integers using common practices.

Comment: You should step through this code in debugger and watch variable values as you do so. Then it will be obvious what is happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Comment: Do you understand what `x&1` is? Can you describe that expression with the help of the term "LSB" ("least signifying bit"). Do you understand what happens to `x` during `x>>=1` ? Can you describe that statement with the help of the term "right-shift"? If you can't, please read up on those operators. If you can, what is your problem otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are printing the value of X variable in binary. For this, your code, use logical operation as AND operator and right-shift.

In the loop condition, you displace the X variable one bit to the right.

```
 for b = 0 you get x = 1010  
 for b = 1 you get x = 101  
 for b = 2 you get x = 10  
 for b = 3 you get x = 1
```

Then, in your print, show your loop iterator (b) and your X variable AND 1.

The AND operator get this values:

```
0 AND 0 = 0   
0 AND 1 = 0  
1 AND 0 = 0  
1 AND 1 = 1
```

In your case, you have:

```
1010 AND (000)1 = 0  
101 AND (00)1 = 1  
10 AND (0)1 = 0  
1 AND 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions in your post: how to access an individual bit ? and how to select that bit ?

Concerning the first question, suppose you want to access the less significant bit (or, to make it simpler, the rightmmost bit), you can use a *mask*: suppose your data is `b0011` for instance, you can mask with `b0001` (i.e. `1` in decimal).

```
  0 0 1 1
& 0 0 0 1
---------
  0 0 0 1
```

The `&` operator is the bitwise `and`. If you look in your code sample, you have `printf("%d:%d\n", b, (x&1));` in which you can see `x & 1`, i.e. print the rightmost bit of `x`.

Now comes the second question: how to put each bit in the rightmost position one after each other (said otherwise, how to select the bit to print) ? An easy solution is to `shift` your data of `1` position to the right each time you want to select the next bit (i.e. the bit to the left of the current one).

In C, you can `shift` using `>>`. For instance, if `x` is `b0011`, then `x >> 1` is `b0001` (in this case, you fill the leftmost position with zeros, but in some cases it might be trickier). If you look in you code sample, you have `x>>=1` in the `for-loop`, which assigns `x >> 1` in `x`.

Hence, suppose you take the previous example:

```
  0 0 1 1 = x                       0 0 0 1 = x
& 0 0 0 1                         & 0 0 0 1
---------    x >> 1 = b0001 -> x  ---------
  0 0 0 1                           0 0 0 1
```

and so one...

A last bonus point, the loop stopping condition is `x != 0`, this implies that you don't prints all bits of your data, but only the bits *up to the leftmost `1` (included)*. For instance, in the above example, after printing the two rightmost bits, `x` becomes `0` and the loop exits.